# How to change value of $menu_class in ep_nav_menu?

Tags: plugins, hooks

How can i change value of $menu_class parameter in wp_nav_menu() so that I can give a special css class to one of items in menu for example 
"Home"?
here is some code but they didn't show me the message at all:

```
function clear_nav_menu_item_id($id, $item, $args) {
    echo "nav_menu_item_id";
}

add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'clear_nav_menu_item_class', 10, 3);
function clear_nav_menu_item_class($classes, $item, $args) {
    echo "nav_menu_css_class";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add any code for this. You can use the `Screen Options` on the menu admin end to achieve this. Please check the instructions below.

- Login to the admin end of your wordpress site and navigate to `Appearance` => `Menus` section.
- Click the down arrow against the menu item you need to have a different class for.
- Then click on the `Screen Options` link on the top right section of your screen.
- Check/click the `CSS Classes` option. Once checked, it will show an additional field `CSS Classes (optional)` below the menu item you had expanded earlier.
- Now provide any custom class in the field and add the respective css code in your theme's css file.

**Note:**

- These steps are based on Wordpress 3.8 version which may slightly vary if you are using a different version.

Comment: I'm making a plugin for this propose please show me a way to do this with plugin.

Comment: You never mentioned this in your question.

Comment: sorry it's hard to ask question correctly

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
/* Add a custom class to a specific menu item */

function my_class( $classes, $item, $args ) {
if($args->theme_location == 'location-slug'){
    if( $item->ID == 1 ) { //By Menu Item ID
        $classes[] = 'menuitemid1';
    }
    if( $item->title == 'Blog' ) { //By Menu Item Title
        $classes[] = 'blogmenuitem';
    }
}
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_class', 10, 2 );
```

Source: [Add Custom Class To WordPress Menu Items](http://www.itsabhik.com/add-custom-class-to-wordpress-menu-items/)

Comment: I apply your code and in my css file write this .menuitemid38{
 background-color: red;
}

Comment: but didn't work then wipe your code so that test the filter with this

Comment: echo "nav_menu_css_class";
 return;

Comment: and it still shows  me nothing

Comment: This goes to your functions.php file (or, in plugin's PHP files in case you are using it in plugin). NOT is the CSS file.

Comment: I know I wrote this code iin my plugin PHP file but it shows me nothing.

Comment: even if i echo simple message

Comment: The code is working and tested. Check the source code of your page. You might need to use `!important` in your CSS rules to override defaults. Anyway, code edited to push the classes to a particular nav menu.

Comment: @moslem Juct checking the obvious, are you replacing this `'location-slug'` with your menu location while using the above code